# How to pass a value from controller to the Datetime picker

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my Create view, there is a `Date picker` to select the date for the user.

Then the edit view, I want to pass the same date values to the edit view.

This is my view property looks like

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date_of_birth, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control js-datepicker", Type = "Date" } })
```

It shows the date picker, but not shows the passed date value.

Answer (score 0):

You should fill the model at action in that controller which you returning Edit view then `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date_of_birth, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control js-datepicker", Type = "Date" } })`
will fill the data for you.

Comment: I have checked, and model data pass from the controller as DateTime. But in the view it doesn't show.